# Why am I not able to update Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, apt

Whenever I try to update my ubuntu from software updater,I get the following message

> > **The package system is broken**
> >     Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems. Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

I ran `sudo apt-get install -f` but after running the command when I tried to update, I got the following message

> **Failed to download package files** 
>   Check your Internet connection.

```
 $ ping -c 2 8.8.8.8
 PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8:
 icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=10.9 ms 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2
 ttl=60 time=11.0 ms

 --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
 2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms rtt
 min/avg/max/mdev = 10.978/11.035/11.093/0.119 ms
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN nameserver 127.0.1.1 search domain.name
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: @Ravexina : Yes, after I run that command and try to update again, I get the following message >>Failed to download package files Check your Internet connection.<<

Comment: Run `ping -c 2 8.8.8.8` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` add the output of these commands to you question.

Comment: Did you disable non-Ubuntu sources?

Comment: @Ravexina I have posted the two outputs to my question.

Comment: @user535733 no, how do i do that?

Comment: @ZishanKhan open this file: `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` with an editor and with root access for example: `sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` add this line to the file: `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, then save the file. after that run `sudo resolvconf -u`. now run `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: What's the output of `host archive.ubuntu.com` vs. `host archive.ubuntu.com 8.8.8.8`? What's the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @Ravexina I opened the file with root access and it reads this->> # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN<<  so should I add that in  a new line ?

Comment: @ZishanKhan Yes, its actually a warning that will appear in `/etc/resolv.conf`. add the line I mentioned at the end of this file. as your outputs indicates you don't have any DNS server, thats what we are trying to set.

Comment: @Ravexina it's still not working  >>root@zishan-Vostro-1440:/home/zishan# sudo resolvconf -u
root@zishan-Vostro-1440:/home/zishan# sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release

Comment: Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Fetched 306 kB in 3s (78.3 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: As I see it's working

Comment: Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
115 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
root@zishan-Vostro-1440:/home/zishan# sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 115 not upgraded.
<<

Comment: It seems that we fixed the DNS issue, your output is to messy, try to put them somewhere like: `paste.ubuntu.com`. then add it to your question.

Comment: I am sorry I am not able to put that in my answer as i do not have enough reputation " to add more than two links to my answer"